# Opening and compiling tex files in subdirectory

Tags: filetype-tex, linux

I am using Linux mint cinnamon. Let's say I have `.tex` file in the sub-directory `~/MyTexfiles/Integration`. When I double click on the `.tex` file to open it, it opens in vim since vim is my default editor, and when I go to compile this file the `.pdf` file and the auxiliary files appear in the home directory. But if I open a new terminal inside `~/MyTexfiles/Integration`, and then open and run the `.tex` file, the `.pdf` and other files appear inside this sub-directory. This second result is a desirable result for me. I compile from the command line using the following

```
:!latexmk -pdf %:r.tex<CR>
```

Is there any change that I can make to this command so that after opening `.tex` files by double-clicking, all resulting files after compilation still appear in the sub-directory? I couldn't find a way to do this, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `latexmk` an extra `-cd` argument to work from the directory where the `*.tex` file is located:

```
:!latexmk -cd -pdf %:r.tex<CR>
```

From the [latexmk(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/latexmk/latexmk.1.en.html) man page:

> **`-cd`**: Change to the directory containing the main source file before processing it. Then all the generated files (`.aux`, `.log`, `.dvi`, `.pdf`, etc) will be relative to the source file.
>
> This option is particularly useful when `latexmk` is invoked from a GUI configured to invoke `latexmk` with a full pathname for the source file.
>
> This option works by setting the `$do_cd` configuration variable to one; you can set that variable if you want to configure `latexmk` to have the effect of the `-cd` option without specifying it on the command line. See the documentation for that variable.

Comment: I wonder if the first instance had cwd of ~?

Comment: A related question, when I open by double-clicking `:pwd` still shows `/home/mahbub`. Is there any setting in the terminal that I can change so that the file in truly opened in `/home/mahbub/MyTexfiles/Integration'`, i.e., `:pwd` shows `/home/mahbub/MyTexfiles/Integration`?

Comment: @MahbubAlam Look at `:help 'autochdir'`.